# GIN trigram index not used when case-insensitive query is performed

Tags: django, postgresql, performance, indexing

- When I query the table using `trigram_similar` or `contains` the index is used, as expected.
- When I query the same table using `icontains`, Django performs a sequential scan using `UPPER`.

The difference is 3ms vs 240ms.

- Should I create a lowercase index and match with `contains`? (How could this be done?)
- Should I create a field where all the contents will be lower cased and index that field?
- Something else?

The model:

```py
class Name(models.Model):
    name_en = models.CharField(max_length=127)
    ...

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            GinIndex(
                name="name_en_gin_trigram",
                fields=["name_en"],
                opclasses=["gin_trgm_ops"],
            )
        ]
```

- The query that uses the index:

  ```py
  >>> Name.objects.filter(
      Q(name_en__contains='eeth')
      | Q(name_en__trigram_similar='eeth')
  )

  SELECT *
  FROM "shop_name"
  WHERE ("shop_name"."name_en"::text LIKE '%eeth%' OR "shop_name"."name_en" % 'eeth')
  LIMIT 21;
  ```

  The resulting query plan:

  ```
  Limit  (cost=64.06..90.08 rows=7 width=121) (actual time=0.447..2.456 rows=14 loops=1)
     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on shop_name  (cost=64.06..90.08 rows=7 width=121) (actual time=0.443..2.411 rows=14 loops=1)
           Recheck Cond: (((name_en)::text ~~ '%eeth%'::text) OR ((name_en)::text % 'eeth'::text))
           Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 236
           Heap Blocks: exact=206
           ->  BitmapOr  (cost=64.06..64.06 rows=7 width=0) (actual time=0.371..0.378 rows=0 loops=1)
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on name_en_gin_trigram  (cost=0.00..20.03 rows=4 width=0) (actual time=0.048..0.049 rows=15 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((name_en)::text ~~ '%eeth%'::text)
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on name_en_gin_trigram  (cost=0.00..44.03 rows=4 width=0) (actual time=0.318..0.320 rows=250 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((name_en)::text % 'eeth'::text)
  Planning Time: 0.793 ms
  Execution Time: 2.531 ms
  (12 rows)
  ```
- If I use `icontains` the index is not used:

  ```py
  >>> Name.objects.filter(
    Q(name_en__icontains='eeth')
    | Q(name_en__trigram_similar='eeth')
  )

  SELECT * 
  FROM "shop_name"
  WHERE (UPPER("shop_name"."name_en"::text) LIKE UPPER('%eeth%') OR "shop_name"."name_en" % 'eeth')
  LIMIT 21;
  ```

  The resulting query plan:

  ```
  Limit  (cost=0.00..95.61 rows=21 width=121) (actual time=10.513..244.244 rows=14 loops=1)
     ->  Seq Scan on shop_name  (cost=0.00..1356.79 rows=298 width=121) (actual time=10.509..244.195 rows=14 loops=1)
           Filter: ((upper((name_en)::text) ~~ '%EETH%'::text) OR ((name_en)::text % 'eeth'::text))
           Rows Removed by Filter: 36774
  Planning Time: 0.740 ms
  Execution Time: 244.299 ms
  (6 rows)
  ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django runs `icontains` with `UPPER()`, and we can address this by making the index also `UPPER()`:

`CREATE INDEX upper_col_name_gin_idx ON table_name USING GIN (UPPER(col_name) gin_trgm_ops)`

Django will then run `WHERE UPPER("table_name"."col_name"::text) LIKE UPPER('%term%')`, using this index.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I assume that using [Index.expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/indexes/#django.db.models.Index.expressions) from Django-3.2, this could also be done in the `Meta` class of `models.Model`.

Answer (score 4):

**Update**: This approach will not work as expected. However, the mechanics can be used to address the [accepted approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68156665/modern-practical-option-for-django-search-with-postgres-need-multiple-criteria).

---

> Should I create a lowercase index and match with contains? (How could this be done?)

From [Django-3.2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/indexes/#django.db.models.Index.expressions):

> Positional argument *expressions allows creating functional indexes on
> expressions and database functions.
>
> For example:
>
> `Index(Lower('title').desc(), 'pub_date', name='lower_title_date_idx')`
>
> creates an index on the lowercased value of the title field in
> descending order and the pub_date field in the default ascending
> order.

It sounds like some quality Django music!

The code used to accomplish the above, is the following:

migrations/0001_initial.py:

```py
'''
A fake migration used to install the necessary extensions.
It should be followed by 
./manage.py makemigrations && ./manage.py migrate
'''

from django.contrib.postgres.operations import (
    BtreeGinExtension, 
    TrigramExtension,
)
from django.db import migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = []

    operations = [
        BtreeGinExtension(),
        TrigramExtension(),
    ]
```

models.py:

```py
from django.contrib.postgres.indexes import GinIndex, OpClass
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.functions import Lower


class Name(models.Model):
    name_en = models.CharField(max_length=127)
    ...

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            GinIndex(
                OpClass(Lower("name_en"), name="gin_trgm_ops"),
                name="name_en_gin_trigram_lowercase",
            ),
        ]
```

[`OpClass`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/postgres/indexes/#opclass-expressions) is used to avoid the error:

> `ValueError: Index.opclasses cannot be used with expressions. Use django.contrib.postgres.indexes.OpClass() instead.`

Comment: Thank you, that was rather non-obvious to put together in django.