# Modern practical option for Django search with Postgres? Need multiple criteria, but icontains is too inefficient

Tags: python, django, postgresql, indexing, django-views

Django search / filter in views.py using `icontains` and `gte`, simplified:

```
def BootstrapFilterView(request):
    qs = Table.objects.all()
    food_contains_query = request.GET.get('food')
    country_contains_query = request.GET.get('country')
    price_min_query = request.GET.get('pmin')

    qs = qs.filter(food__icontains= food_contains_query)
    qs = qs.filter(country__icontains= country_contains_query)
    qs = qs.filter(price__gte=price_min_query)
```

`gte` works fine but upon testing `icontains` is unsuitably inefficient. Indexing doesn't help for `icontains` and I think `iexact` might work, but users can't be expected to provide exact matches. I'm bewildered by more advanced options for a task well beyond my understanding and am reluctant to attempt [potentially obsolete approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55056/whats-the-best-django-search-app).

Using Postgres 11.6 with millions of rows, and need multiple optional search criteria. There are thousands of unique `food` and all are children of one of dozens of `country`.

[Django Postgres has full text search](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/search/) but all search criteria are nouns so don't need lexeme conversion but spelling correction (eg. "burito" → "burrito") and synonym matching (eg. "hamburger" → "cheeseburger") are desirable. Is Postgres full text suitable and can this be used with other search criteria of `gte` and similar numeric operations?

What's a modern and practical way to improve performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. For `icontains` enable `pg_tgrm` extension and use a GIN index with `UPPER()`:

`CREATE INDEX gin_index_name on table_name USING GIN (UPPER(col_name) gin_trgm_ops);`

Answer (score 1):

Thousands is not that many, and thousands divided by dozens is even less many.  You can probably load this all in the frontend and do type-a-head suggestions and typo spotting in the frontend, then deal with only exact string matches in the database.  That would make a btree index on `(food, price)` very efficient.  (Presumably country is unneeded as the food implies the country, or does it not work that way?)

Comment: `food` and `country` were chosen for example simplicity. In retrospect `cuisine` is better. They're child : parent like Paris : France. There are also grandchildren. I don't know B-Trees but don't they need a value for all fields? I'd like the search criteria to be optional.